# Why this apache logs showing private ip as client ip?

Tags: apache, http, logging

just want to ask what does this apache logs mean? Although i know some of the meaning but did not really understand this logs line..

```
10.xx.x.xx - - [08/Dec/2021:08:06:12 +0000] "POST /endpoint HTTP/1.1" 200 511 "-" "PHP Curl/1.9 (+https://github.com/php-mod/curl)" "157.xxx.xx.xxx, 172.70.xxx.xxx"
```

My Server A (157.xxx.xx.xxx) is calling a http post method to another server B. So in this case not sure what kind of server config causing the client ip infront of the log showing that 10.xx.x.xx (look like private ip?) but my Server A ip is showing at behind as user agent and there is another ip show after my Server A iP (172.70.xxx.xxx)?

I suspect that the ip 10.xx.x.xx maybe is somekind of proxy or gateway ip? Maybe load balancer, nginx, cloudflare or etc?

Can anyone help to explain this? Thanks guys..

Comment: Check if server B is using nginx+apache and if server B has set 10.xx.x.xx as one of its ips.  If yes then you should install `mod_remoteip` in server B.